# Custom Table Cells with PFQueryTableViewController with PARSE in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

All,

I have got the cells working fine with a normal cell, but I am trying to create a custom cell with a nib etc and then link that into PARSE using PFQueryTableViewController.

Here is my code :

```
class CustomCell: PFTableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet var EventTypeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

    }




class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {



    override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.parseClassName = "Events_"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = true
        //self.objectsPerPage = 5
        //self.textKey = "TypeOfVenue_"
     }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        var nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    }



    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {

        var query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName)

        if (objects.count == 0)
        {
            query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly
        }

        return query


    }



     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell!
     {
        var custom = CustomCell()

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as PFTableViewCell!

        custom.titleLabel?.text = object["Title"] as NSString
        return cell


     }
```

So I have created a custom cell and linked it with the CustomCell Class at the top. In CellForRowatIndexPath. I have created a new instance of the CustomCell Class and got the titlelabel from it and then Casted it to NSstring and used PARSE to get the 'object'.

I don't have any errors. All I get on the tableview is a spinning wheel saying Loading.

Any advice would be brilliant.

Comment: Try nib.self when registering it

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar problem, where the nib wasn't getting loaded. I then realized I could create the custom cell right in the prototype of the tableviewcontroller in the storyboard, which I did, and changed the class in the identity inspector as shown. Here QuestionCell would be your custom cell file.

[image]

I would separate CustomCell into a different and make sure you have that selected in the prototype identity inspector. As well, make sure the style is custom, and make sure any of the labels are connected in the storyboard with the iboutlets in the new CustomCell class.

[image]

Then, you can delete the

```
var nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

since you are using the prototype.

Then replace

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as PFTableViewCell!
```

with

```
var cell:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCell
```

and you should be good to go! Let me know if this works!

Answer (score -1):

I also had a spinning loading wheel while adding initializer properties to this init method:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

But doing this, instead, worked:

```
//class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController

override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)

    self.parseClassName = "todo"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 30
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
}
```